# How to resize text boxes in fullcalender to accommodate more text

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

[image: This is the screenshot of my resulting calendar. You can view it at etabeta.sudz.dev]

Here is the code that generates fullcalendar, it is based off of the template included in the fullcalendar examples with a few modifications.

```js
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import googleCalendarPlugin from '@fullcalendar/google-calendar';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';



import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');

import bootbox from 'bootbox';


require('./styles/core/main.min.css');
require('./styles/daygrid/main.min.css');
require('./styles/list/main.min.css');
require('./styles/timegrid/main.min.css');

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
if (calendarEl){
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    eventClick: function(info) {
      if (info.event.extendedProps.description){
      bootbox.alert('Event: ' +  info.event.title + '<br>'  + 'Description: ' + info.event.extendedProps.description);
      }
      else {
        bootbox.alert('Event: ' +  info.event.title + '<br>' + 'Description: ' + 'none');
      }
      info.jsEvent.preventDefault(); // don't let the browser navigate

    },

    plugins: [ interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin ],
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'redacted',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listWeek'
    },
    //defaultDate: '2018-01-12',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: {
        googleCalendarId: 'l1rnqsakc8kb0lbmo2ll3ag5v0@group.calendar.google.com'
  }

  });
   calendar.render();

});
}
```

Here is the calendar.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset='utf-8' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>
  body {
    margin: 40px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  #calendar {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .fc-day-grid-event > .fc-content {
    white-space: normal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <br>
  <div class="container">
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have figured out how to allow more than one line per square in the calendar by modifying the css to remove the no-wrap attribute but I have no idea how to make sure that the squares automatically expand to accommodate for this new text that has been added. If anyone is familiar with fullcalendar, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have found an example of what I am trying to accomplish here: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/2JFg5y but I am not sure how my code is any different from that example

Comment: Please provide your HTML + CSS, we can't make many recommendations without them!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I completely forgot - sorry

Comment: Please check this out - [height](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/height)

Comment: As far as I understand the height attribute is for the entire calendar so even if I did increase the height this wouldn't help my problem. I am interested in increasing the height for a specific row that is overflowing with text  and not have each row be a static height that is a ratio to that of the entire calendar.

Comment: If I changed the height of the entire calendar then I would have a lot of wasted space in rows for which there is no text at all

Comment: That plunkr uses an ancient version of fullCalendar, that's the main difference. But there's no obvious reason why version 4, using your extra CSS, wouldn't behave the same. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/LYYObVG . Perhaps there's some other difference you aren't showing us, or something related to the actual content of your events which causes it. It's hard to know, we don't have the full picture.